# Building kiosk applications

Tags: java, .net, kiosk

I have a requirement which is to build and deploy a custom application for a kiosk. I have read some materials online on how to build one but none has satisfied my curiosity. My concern s are this:

1) When an ATM Card is entered into the kiosk, how do i detect the ATM Card and get the necessary details?

2) Is there an API that i need to get from the manufacturer of kiosk?

3) How do i add additional menu that leads to my application on the kiosk.

Thanks!

Comment: you pretty much asked "how to build java application"

Comment: It always depends your hardware mannual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) When an ATM Card is entered into the kiosk, how do i detect the ATM Card and get the necessary details?

Your program should listen to an event or poll for event to occur. It completely depends on the hardware you are using to get the ATM card information. There should be an SDK comes with hardware. Find the docs.

> 2) Is there an API that i need to get from the manufacturer of kiosk?

If the kiosk itself is the hardware get it from manufacturer. Many kiosk adds a hardware with it that interface ATM card. In that case try to get API/Docs/SDK for that hardware manufacturer.